# Try to install django-cms in a shared host

Tags: django, django-cms

can I install django-cms（from www.django-cms.org） in a shared hosting without shell access? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

The real question is: "Can I run Django in a shared host?". django-cms is just package, it needs Django to run and Django is likely going to be your limiting factor there, not django-cms.

So, the answer to that is a resounding "Maybe". Technically, if you run all your Python packages in a virtualenv, including Django and django-cms, you shouldn't need root/sudo privileges. *But*, and it's a big but, that assumes your shared hosting provide makes virtualenv available to you. If they support Python *at all* you should be good, but even then, who knows.

However, shared hosting is really not appropriate in general for anything like Django. Even if you can get it to run, performance will surely be an issue. Nowadays, there's really *zero* reason not to just jump to a VPS. You can get your own little VPS over at Rackspace for ~$11/mo. That's cheap -- like possibly cheaper than what you're paying for shared hosting cheap.

Just make the leap and stop living in limited shared environment. It's worth every penny.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Performance isn't a big deal for me, I didn't plan to build a production site. lol

Comment: That's sort of more to the point. If you're just toying around, you might as well learn how to do it right. If and when you do deploy a production site, your experience on shared hosting will not be helpful.

Comment: this is exactly the info I was looking for @chrisPratt